# What settings need to change if I change the name of a MDT/WDS server?

Tags: wds, mdt-2010

I recently ran into an issue where my Windows Deployment Services server stopped working after changing the name of the server. After looking around, I didn't really find a good answer for what settings need to be updated if you change the name of your WDS server.

Answering this below per the comment.

Comment: This is great, except that you shouldn't format it the way that you did. You should ask the question in the question field and then answer your own question. Then accept that answer when the system allows you to. If you just leave it as-is, it will constantly be bumped and will be marked as "unanswered", which is bad.

Comment: Plus, you get double rep this way :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found all the different places that it needs to be updated but wanted to document them here incase anybody else ever runs into a similar issue.

- DeploymentWorkbench > Deployment Shares > Share Name > right-click > Properties > General > Network (UNC) path
- DeploymentWorkbench > Deployment Shares > Share Name > right-click > Properties > Rules > Edit Bootstrap.ini > DeployRoot=\servername\directorylocation
- \servername\deploymentshare$\control > Edit CustomSettings.ini > If the server name is included anywhere in this file, update it
- \servername\deploymentshare$\control\deployment\ > Edit Unattend.xml > Do a find a for the old server name and replace with the new one

After this, update the package, redeploy a new image to it, and everything should be up and running!

Comment: You might have to change the "Monitoring host:" too in the deployment share properties.

Comment: Also you need to replace the boot wim in WDS.